# Extremal points of a sum of trigonometric functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, trigonometric-series

Show that the sum of trigonometric functions

$$
f(x,y,z)=\cos(x+y+\alpha_1)+\cos(x-y+\alpha_2)+\cos(y+z+\alpha_3)\\+\cos(y-z+\alpha_4)+\cos(x+z+\alpha_5)+ \cos(x-z+\alpha_6)
$$

where the $\alpha_i$ are arbitrary angles, does not have any local-but-not-global maximum or minimum.

The same result seems true for the more general case $\sum_{i=1}^n\cos(\vec{v}_i.\vec{x}+\alpha_i)$ where $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ are the variables and $\vec{v}_i$ are vectors with entries equal to $0$, $1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $y, z$ fixed.

Then $f(x,)=\cos(x+\beta_1)+\cos(x+\beta_2)+\cos(\beta_3)+\cos(\beta_4)+\cos(x+\beta_5)+ \cos(x+\beta_6)$

We know that $\cos(x+\theta)$ can be written $A\cos x+B\sin x$,

so $f(x)=A_1\cos x+B_1\sin x + A_2\cos x+B_2\sin x+ C_3+C_4+A_5\cos x+B_5\sin x+A_6\cos x+B_6\sin x$

Then $f(x)=K\cos x+L\sin x + M= R\cos(x+\gamma)+M$

We know from the properties of the $\cos$ function that this has no local-but-not-global maximum or minimum.

Extend in other directions.